# Slightly jagged edges in chrome (CSS transform)

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-transforms

I've some issues with a *transform:rotate* on Chrome (v54 / Windows 10) and others modern navigators I could test (Edge, Firefox... IE), actually. The edges of my div are a bit jagged, it's not as horrible as it was in Chrome's version of 2012 but it still not perfect.

I tried several tricks as

```
backface-visibility: hidden;
transform: translate3d( 0, 0, 0);
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
```

but none of them seems to completely work. The result is smoother than the initial one but still not fully satisfying.

Here's a link to my jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/2szkvj70/1/

and a screenshot :

[image]

Am I a bit too exigent or is it possible to get the perfect no-aliased result ? :)

Thanks in advance !

Comment: If it is any consolation, it looks exactly the same to me in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari on Mac.

Comment: @mherzig It's something.

Comment: It seems like in Google Chrome v55 the have improved jagged edges a lot!?

Comment: @Alfred I just installed v56 (Beta) and there isn't any improvement actually. [Screenshot](https://vgy.me/mGeJWi.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this by adjusting your CSS slightly:

`outline: 1px solid transparent;`

instead of:

`outline: 1px transparent;`

https://jsfiddle.net/2szkvj70/2/ - This provides a comparison.

Comment: Just tried and nope, didn't work. Sadly. :< Here's a screenshot of the result, on my computer. [Screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/YJbFPju.png)